# Display a new view when button in cell is pressed

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have data displayed in a customized cell view. A cell contains a title and a button. When a user clicks on the button, the page will re-direct to a new view.

Now what I need to do is, when the user clicks on the button (and not the cell), the title of the cell should be displayed on the new view that
will be loaded. How should I code this?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using a touch on the cell itself for this? Then you'd know exactly what cell it was without any work at all (via the indexPath argument of didSelectRowAtIndexPath:).

Comment: In the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` gets selected when you click the cell, but i am clicking the `button` in that cell, so i need to get the name of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few tips you should try out.

1. When you push the view controller ( inside the `IBaction` of that button that gets pressed) to the next view, implement the title of the next view accordingly.
2. Use `tags` for the buttons and logically form a link between them and the `uiTableViewCell` in which you implemented the button.
3. Set the `cell.textLabel.text` value to the `nextViewController.title`.

Comment: I don't undestand the 2nd step, can you further explain it, or provide a tutorial/sample code

Answer (score 0):

You must first add button to cell and set button as Accessory of Table Cell :

```
    myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
    [myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 20, 10)];
    [cell addSubview:myButton];
    cell.accessoryView = myButton;
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector (ActionMethod) 
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Now in the ActionMethod you have to put the logic for pushing it to a new view :

```
    -(void) ActionMethod
   {
        myViewController *Obj=[[myViewController alloc]init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:Obj animated:NO];
        [Obj release];
   }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: But the problem is he also need to know which cell's button has been pressed, in your solution all buttons will open the same page.